# Need help understanding part of proof of lemma used to prove Egorov's theorem from Royden's Real Analysis, chapter $3$.

Tags: real-analysis

The lemma for reference with the proof is here:

> **Lemma $\mathbf{10}$:** Under the assumptions of Egoroff's Theorem, for each $\eta>0$ and $\delta>0$, there is a measurable subset $A$ of $E$ and an index $N$ for which
> $$|f_n-f|<\eta\text{ on }A\text{ for all }n\ge N\text{ and }m(E\sim A)<\delta.$$
>
> **Proof:** For each $k$, the function $|f-f_k|$ is properly defined, since $f$ is real-valued, and it is measurable, so that the set $\{x\in E\text{ }\vert\text{ }|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\eta\}$ is measurable. The intersection of a countable collection of measurable sets is measurable. Therefore
> $$E_n=\{x\in E\text{ }\vert\text{ }|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\eta\text{ for all }k\ge n\}$$
> is a measurable set. Then $\{E_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ is an ascending collection of measurable sets, and $\color{blue}{E=\cup^\infty_{n=1}E_n\text{, since $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to }\text{$f$ on $E$}}$. We infer from the continuity of measure that
> $$m(E)=\lim_{n\to\infty} m(E_n).$$
> Since $m(E)<\infty$, we may choose an index $N$ for which $m(E_N)>m(E)-\epsilon$. Define $A=E_n$ and observe that, by the excision property of measure, $m(E\sim A)=m(E)-m(E_N)<\epsilon$.

I've highlighted the bit I don't understand in blue. Why does pointwise convergence imply $E = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$?

The assumptions of Egorov's theorem that the author's referencing are:

> **Egoroff's Theorem**:
>
> Assume $E$ has finite measure. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $E$ that converges pointwise one $E$ to the real-valued function $f$. Then for each $\epsilon>0$, there is a closed set $F$ contained in $E$ for which
> $$\{f_n\}\rightarrow f \text{ uniformly on } F  \text{ and } m(E\sim F)<\epsilon$$

Comment: Notice that $\{x: f_n(x)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow}f(x)\}=\bigcap_n\bigcup_m\bigcap_{k\geq m}\{x:|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\frac1n\}$

Comment: Thank you, @OliverDíaz. Can you please add some more to say how one is supposed to figure this out? It's hard enough for me just to check that the two sets are equal.

Comment: Recall what it means, in terms of $\varepsilon$ and $N_\varepsilon$, for a sequence of function $f_n$, to converge to another function $f$ at a point $x$. The quantifier *for all* is associated to intersection, the quantifier *exists* or *there is* is associated to union. As integration and measure theory deal with countable sets, instead of having for all $\varepsilon$, we may have for all $\varepsilon_n=\frac{1}{n}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, etc.

Comment: @OliverDíaz: Super helpful. Thank you so much.